# Python return list of values associated with specific key in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts :

```
my_dict = [{'Serial': 'AAAAAA', 'Slave_ID': 2},{'Serial': 'BBBBBB', 'Slave_ID': 3}, {'Serial': 'AAAAAA', 'Slave_ID': 5}]
```

Could someone suggest me a way to extract the list of slave_ID's for a particular Serial number? For example(pseudo code):

```
Extract_slave_id('AAAAAA'):
   #returns a list of slave id's associated with serial 'AAAAAA'
   list = [5,2]
   return list
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: See if this question is helpful for you [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901798/extract-data-using-regular-expressions-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [{'Serial': 'AAAAAA', 'Slave_ID': 2}, {'Serial': 'BBBBBB', 'Slave_ID': 3},
        {'Serial': 'AAAAAA', 'Slave_ID': 5}]


def extract_slave_ids(slave_id, data):
    return [item['Slave_ID'] for item in data if item['Serial'] == slave_id]


print(extract_slave_ids('AAAAAA', data))
```

Outputs:

```
[2, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you for help. This works exactly as I need. Also helped me understand a little more how the dictionaries work.

Answer (score 2):

```py
my_id = 'AAAAAA'
extracted_ids = [element['Slave_ID'] for element in my_dict if element['Serial'] == my_id]
```